# SRAT:Hotplug area too small

Tags: centos, vmware

I've got a VM (CentOS 6.5 guest) running under VMWare Player. Whenever I switch it on, the message "SRAT: Hotplug area too small" appears. Searching on Google didn't reveal any help, except that it's most likely related to the size of virtual RAM allocated for the machine. (3GB, but it's that much for a reason.)

1. What does the message mean?
2. How to get rid of it?
3. Could I run into problems by ignoring it?

Thanks,

Jochen

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following option in my *.vmx file: `mem.hotadd = "FALSE"`

By default it is set to "TRUE". I've not seen any issues changing it...

Comment: Could you explain what this value is for?